# Non-uint256 TokenID for 721/1155 NFTs? (arbitrary var types)

Tags: ink, smart-contract, nft

I'm using an InkLang implementation for 721Light/1155 (undecided)
For my purpose, the contract is offering domain-like NFTs. So an infinite amount of IDs, but a max balance of 1 for any ID.
From what I'm seeing for Solidity, the tokenID type has to be uint256 to comply with IERCs and the general market.

Would the same go for the InkLang implementations?
Should I encode string->uint256 offchain or otherwise have to create my own interface?
Market support is desired but not explicitly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

For WASM implementation of Fungible(Erc20), Non-Fungible(Erc721), and Multi tokens(Erc1155) were created own standards.

- [PSP22 - Fungible token](https://github.com/w3f/PSPs/blob/master/PSPs/psp-22.md)
- [PSP34 - Non-fungible token](https://github.com/w3f/PSPs/blob/master/PSPs/psp-34.md)
- [PSP35 - Multi token](https://github.com/w3f/PSPs/blob/master/PSPs/drafts/psp-35.md)